# Cannot refer to a non-final variable myVariable inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-volley

maybe i can't explain exactly my problem but with the code below i hope that helps you to answering my question. am trying to pass a String data between two Activities using Intent, in the same time, inside my StringRequest, i use jSonObject to recuperate data from server using volley, so i'd like to know how to put the sames variables recuperated from server to second activity using putExtra, because i have problem of modifier, if a remove modifier for my variables i have an error in the putExtra it should be final modifier and if i put it i have an error with my jsonobject, So, what's the solution please ? thank's in advance.

```
String idMed;               
final String numTelMed;
final String communeMed;
final String nomMed;
final String emailMed;
final String codePostalMed;
final String prenomMed;
final String rueMed;
final String villeMed;
final String specialiteMed;
final String latitude;
final String longitude;
ListView listeView;

listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
List<String> listeMed = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listeMed);
listeView.setAdapter(adapter1);


JSONArray jObjectSearch = new JSONArray(response);
Log.i("OK","JSONObjectOK : "+jObjectSearch);
Log.i("OK","JSONObjectOK : "+jObjectSearch.getString(0));
for(int i=0; i<jObjectSearch.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject  j = new JSONObject(jObjectSearch.getString(0));
    idMed = j.getString("id");
    nomMed = j.getString("nomMed");
    prenomMed = j.getString("prenomMed");
    numTelMed = j.getString("numTelMed");
    emailMed = j.getString("emailMed");
    rueMed = j.getString("rueMed");
    communeMed = j.getString("communeMed");
    codePostalMed = j.getString("codePostalMed");
    villeMed = j.getString("villeMed");
    specialiteMed = j.getString("specialiteMed");
    latitude = j.getString("latitude");
    longitude = j.getString("longitude");

    listeMed.add("Nom : "+nomMed+"\n "+"Prénom : "+prenomMed+"\n "+"Numéro Téléphone : "+numTelMed+"\n "
              +"Email : "+emailMed+"\n "+"Adresse : "+rueMed+" "+codePostalMed+" "
              +villeMed+" "+communeMed+"\n "+"Spécialité : "+specialiteMed);

     listeView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            medecinSearched = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, MedecinSearched.class);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("nomMed", nomMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("prenomMed", prenomMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("numTelMed", numTelMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("emailMed", emailMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("rueMed", rueMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("communeMed", communeMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("codePostalMed", codePostalMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("villeMed", villeMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("specialiteMed", specialiteMed);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("longitude", longitude);

            startActivity(medecinSearched);
            finish();


        }

    });

}
```

Comment: put everything that is in the onItemClick into a separate function and call it from within the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a variable inside an anonymous class you have to use the final keyword.

However, in this case I would solve this with another approach:

- Create a `Med` class with all the properties you need id, nom, prenom, etc.
- Create a `MedAdapter` extending `BaseAdapter` instead of using an `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

onCreate method:

```
listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
listeMed = new ArrayList<Med>();
MedAdapter adapter1 = new MedAdapter<String>(Main_Activity.this, listeMed);
listeView.setAdapter(adapter1);
listeView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Med med = listeMed.get(position);
            Intent medecinSearched = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, MedecinSearched.class);
            medecinSearched.putExtra("EXTRA_MED", med); // Med must implement Serializable or Parcelable
            startActivity(medecinSearched);
            finish();
        }
});
```

Response callback:

```
JSONArray jObjectSearch = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0; i<jObjectSearch.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jObjectSearch.getString(0));
    Med med = new Med(jsonObject); // Med must have a constructor which receives the JSONObject.
    listeMed.add(med);
}
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank's fernandospr

Answer (score 0):

thank's for All, it helps me so much

I have solution but i don't know if it has an inconvenient, here is my solution :
`

```
                            String idMed;             String numTelMed;  String communeMed;
                             String nomMed;          String emailMed;   String codePostalMed;
                             String prenomMed;       String rueMed;     String villeMed;
                             String specialiteMed;   String latitude;   String longitude;
                            ListView listeView;

                            listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
                            List<String> listeMed = new ArrayList<String>();
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listeMed);
                            listeView.setAdapter(adapter1);


                            JSONArray jObjectSearch = new JSONArray(response);
                            Log.i("OK","JSONObjectOK : "+jObjectSearch);
                            Log.i("OK","JSONObjectOK : "+jObjectSearch.getString(0));
                            for(int i=0; i<jObjectSearch.length();i++)
                            {
                             JSONObject  j = new JSONObject(jObjectSearch.getString(0));
                            final String idMedF = idMed = j.getString("id");
                            final String nomMedF = nomMed = j.getString("nomMed");
                            final String prenomMedF =prenomMed = j.getString("prenomMed");
                            final String numTelMedF =numTelMed = j.getString("numTelMed");
                            final String emailMedF =emailMed = j.getString("emailMed");
                            final String rueMedF= rueMed = j.getString("rueMed");
                            final String communeMedF =communeMed = j.getString("communeMed");
                            final String codePostalMedF = codePostalMed = j.getString("codePostalMed");
                            final String villeMedF =villeMed = j.getString("villeMed");
                            final String specialiteMedF =specialiteMed = j.getString("specialiteMed");
                            final double latitudeF =  j.getDouble("latitude");
                            final double longitudeF =  j.getDouble("longitude");

                              listeMed.add("Nom : "+nomMed+"\n "+"Prénom : "+prenomMed+"\n "+"Numéro Téléphone : "+numTelMed+"\n "
                                          +"Email : "+emailMed+"\n "+"Adresse : "+rueMed+" "+codePostalMed+" "
                                          +villeMed+" "+communeMed+"\n "+"Spécialité : "+specialiteMed);

                                 listeView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                               putData(idMedF, nomMedF, prenomMedF, numTelMedF, emailMedF, rueMedF, communeMedF, codePostalMedF, villeMedF, specialiteMedF, latitudeF, longitudeF);


                                                }

                                      });


                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                }`
```